# Using sqlite and dplyr for fuzzy matching in R

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, string-matching, fuzzy

I am working with an extremely large dataset of names and using RSQlite to run it in R. I have taken the original file (14 million rows) and grouped identical names together using "group by" dplyr. I'm also making sure that separate columns count the number of times the values have been grouped and what their mean scores are. It is a single file, I am not matching it against a master file. This works well, but only reduces the file down to about 5 million rows based on identical string matching.

Is there any way to group names together through a fuzzy match, while keeping the count and mean variables?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
employees <- company %>%
select(name, score)

head(employees)

employeescores <- employees %>%
group_by(name) %>%
summarize(count = n(), score = mean(score))

write.csv(employeescores, file = "employeescores.csv",
row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: How many employees *should* the data have? How will you handle employees that share a name? (Someone else in my company has the same name as I do, and we have far fewer employees than you do). Going back to the raw data and adding unique ID's (e.g., employee id number) may be the only complete solution. Fuzzy matching here is hard because it will likely require intervention to decide how close is close "enough." I have done pairwise string matching, cluster the results, then manually determine if clusters are valid, but that won't work for 5 million unique names. Reproducible data would help.

Comment: If we can assume hypothetically that the names in my dataset are more unique than you might expect and that I'm mostly dealing with punctuation/spelling/prefixes/suffixes, what would be a good first cut approach to dealing with this? Especially if I were interested in checking things manually later?

Comment: The function `utils::adist` is probably where you want to start. However, pairwise comparison across 5 million names is going to be a bit extreme. If you have a database of standardized names, I might start by identifying the best match to your database. That is, for each unique name, find the single best match from your known roster and then assign that as a new column (e.g. "bestMatchName") and print the unique matches (from the scores data) when you summarize to confirm that all of the matches are legit.